# Runninng new kafka server throws exception saying port 9092 alrady in use even when I have changed port in porperties file

Tags: apache-kafka

In `server-1.properties` I changed the port, log and broker id but when I start this `server-1` it throws

> KafkaException : Socket server failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:9092: Address already in use.

And logs I see other properties are changed but port is `9092`

This is `server-1.properties` file :

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=1

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9093
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9093

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

And this is what happens on terminal

```
webwerks@webwerks-H81M-S:~/kafka_2.12-2.2.0$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties &
[3] 16578
[2]   Exit 1                  bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties
webwerks@webwerks-H81M-S:~/kafka_2.12-2.2.0$ 
[2019-07-05 14:42:15,874] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,188] INFO Cluster ID = JNX6PuhSQqWjkA785Kl5tQ (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,190] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /tmp/kafka-logs-1/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,249] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
    advertised.host.name = null
    advertised.listeners = null
    advertised.port = null
    alter.config.policy.class.name = null
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    authorizer.class.name = 
    auto.create.topics.enable = true
    auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
    background.threads = 10
    broker.id = 1
    broker.id.generation.enable = true
    broker.rack = null
    client.quota.callback.class = null
    compression.type = producer
    connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
    connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
    connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
    control.plane.listener.name = null
    controlled.shutdown.enable = true
    controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
    controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
    controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    create.topic.policy.class.name = null
    default.replication.factor = 1
    delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
    delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
    delegation.token.master.key = null
    delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
    delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
    delete.topic.enable = true
    fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
    group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
    group.max.size = 2147483647
    group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    host.name = 
    inter.broker.listener.name = null
    inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.2-IV1
    kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
    kafka.metrics.reporters = []
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
    leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
    listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
    listeners = null
    log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
    log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
    log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
    log.cleaner.enable = true
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
    log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
    log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
    log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
    log.cleaner.threads = 1
    log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
    log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.dirs = /tmp/kafka-logs-1
    log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.interval.ms = null
    log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
    log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
    log.message.downconversion.enable = true
    log.message.format.version = 2.2-IV1
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    log.preallocate = false
    log.retention.bytes = -1
    log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
    log.retention.hours = 168
    log.retention.minutes = null
    log.retention.ms = null
    log.roll.hours = 168
    log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
    log.roll.jitter.ms = null
    log.roll.ms = null
    log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
    max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
    max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
    message.max.bytes = 1000012
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    min.insync.replicas = 1
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
    num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
    num.replica.fetchers = 1
    offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
    offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
    offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
    offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
    offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
    offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
    offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
    offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
    offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
    password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    password.encoder.iterations = 4096
    password.encoder.key.length = 128
    password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
    password.encoder.old.secret = null
    password.encoder.secret = null
    port = 9092
    principal.builder.class = null
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    queued.max.request.bytes = -1
    queued.max.requests = 500
    quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.window.num = 11
    quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
    replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
    replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
    replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
    replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
    replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
    replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
    replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    replication.quota.window.num = 11
    replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
    security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
    socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
    socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = []
    ssl.client.auth = none
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.principal.mapping.rules = [DEFAULT]
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
    transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
    transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
    transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
    unclean.leader.election.enable = false
    zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
    zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.set.acl = false
    zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,258] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
    advertised.host.name = null
    advertised.listeners = null
    advertised.port = null
    alter.config.policy.class.name = null
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    authorizer.class.name = 
    auto.create.topics.enable = true
    auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
    background.threads = 10
    broker.id = 1
    broker.id.generation.enable = true
    broker.rack = null
    client.quota.callback.class = null
    compression.type = producer
    connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
    connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
    connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
    control.plane.listener.name = null
    controlled.shutdown.enable = true
    controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
    controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
    controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    create.topic.policy.class.name = null
    default.replication.factor = 1
    delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
    delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
    delegation.token.master.key = null
    delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
    delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
    delete.topic.enable = true
    fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
    group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
    group.max.size = 2147483647
    group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    host.name = 
    inter.broker.listener.name = null
    inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.2-IV1
    kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
    kafka.metrics.reporters = []
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
    leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
    listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
    listeners = null
    log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
    log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
    log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
    log.cleaner.enable = true
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
    log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
    log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
    log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
    log.cleaner.threads = 1
    log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
    log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.dirs = /tmp/kafka-logs-1
    log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.interval.ms = null
    log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
    log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
    log.message.downconversion.enable = true
    log.message.format.version = 2.2-IV1
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    log.preallocate = false
    log.retention.bytes = -1
    log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
    log.retention.hours = 168
    log.retention.minutes = null
    log.retention.ms = null
    log.roll.hours = 168
    log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
    log.roll.jitter.ms = null
    log.roll.ms = null
    log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
    max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
    max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
    message.max.bytes = 1000012
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    min.insync.replicas = 1
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
    num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
    num.replica.fetchers = 1
    offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
    offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
    offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
    offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
    offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
    offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
    offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
    offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
    offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
    password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    password.encoder.iterations = 4096
    password.encoder.key.length = 128
    password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
    password.encoder.old.secret = null
    password.encoder.secret = null
    port = 9092
    principal.builder.class = null
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    queued.max.request.bytes = -1
    queued.max.requests = 500
    quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.window.num = 11
    quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
    replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
    replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
    replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
    replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
    replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
    replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
    replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    replication.quota.window.num = 11
    replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
    security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
    socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
    socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = []
    ssl.client.auth = none
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.principal.mapping.rules = [DEFAULT]
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
    transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
    transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
    transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
    unclean.leader.election.enable = false
    zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
    zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.set.acl = false
    zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,278] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,278] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,279] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,305] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,312] INFO Logs loading complete in 6 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,327] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,331] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,573] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:9092: Address already in use.
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:573)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:451)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.createAcceptor(SocketServer.scala:245)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1(SocketServer.scala:215)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.$anonfun$createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.createDataPlaneAcceptorsAndProcessors(SocketServer.scala:214)
    at kafka.network.SocketServer.startup(SocketServer.scala:114)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:253)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:569)
    ... 13 more
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,575] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,576] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Stopping socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,578] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Stopped socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,580] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,601] INFO Shutdown complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,602] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,625] INFO Session: 0x10000131261000d closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,626] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000131261000d (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,626] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2019-07-05 14:42:16,626] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:17,278] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:17,278] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:17,279] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:18,279] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:18,279] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:18,279] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:19,279] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:19,279] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2019-07-05 14:42:19,282] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Shutting down socket server (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2019-07-05 14:42:19,320] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Shutdown completed (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2019-07-05 14:42:19,324] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2019-07-05 14:42:19,324] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2019-07-05 14:42:19,325] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shutting down (kafka.server.Ka
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the hash (#) at the beginning of the line, otherwise it's a comment and the default value is picked!

Change:

```
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9093
```

To:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9093
```